# What's the proper synonym for purchase when used in real-estate context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english, synonyms, business-language, software

How to say

- Buying Price
- Purchase Price
- You name it

Note, I need the 'buying' term, as opposed to Sale Price.

It's for a form where the user should fill in how much he paid for the apartment and for how much he sold it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Purchase Price* works for me, especially if you put it just before *Sale Price* on the form.

Comment: What's aquisition? I want it to sound 'professional', got me?

Comment: Not too professional tho, not geeky

Comment: @Shimmy **acquisition** [note the ***c*** ]: An asset or object bought or obtained, typically by a library or museum. (or a publisher, etc.); An act of purchase of one company by another. Though it roughly means 'purchase', it is more narrowly defined than 'purchase'. If you mean the cost of the property including taxes, duties, civic/development charges..., then go ahead and call it 'Acquisition Price' (cost of acquisition).